# Getting Virtual Memory Max Map Count in Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, memory, virtual, sysctl

How to get 'sysctl vm.max_map_count',  or the '/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count' using C++

I do not want to open the /proc/sys file..
Is there a http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html call to get the number ?

Comment: `I do not want to open the /proc/sys file` why?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I already use sysctl and other libc.so.6 calls without opening /proc files and I want to keep it this way

Comment: Have you tried the `sysctl` system call?

Comment: @Simon Kraemer - I was able to set new max map count from bash using sysctl, but when I : 'strace -v sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=12345' the sysctl command doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: So what is your question? That the sysctl command doesn't use the sysctl function? I honestly don't get your problem. Please update your question description so we actually know what you have tried so far and where you encounter a problem.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer - I asked how to get the max map count value using C++ code. using a syscall...  but not using 'open /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count'.   I want to do that the same way the kernel does.  I think my question describes that

Comment: And why don't you just use the sysctl syscall?

Comment: @Simon Kraemer - that is my question : how to use sysctl syscall to get max map count

Comment: Without any further knowledge or being able to try it out at the moment: I would initialize the `__sysctl_args` with `name="vm.max_map_count"` and  `nlen=16` and the remaining fields with `0`  or `nullptr`.

Comment: Update: I would recommend you provide a reasonable sized buffer for `newval` and set `newlen` accordingly

Comment: Tried that with name = int [] { VM_MAX_MAP_COUNT } .  sysctl returning -1 with errno = 20 (ENOTDIR) which means it doesn't find the name. I tried with name = 22 with no help either.   I'm including sys/sysctl.h + linux/sysctl.h.    On standard ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

This sysctl command will return a key value pair.

```
sysctl -q vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = xxxxxx
```

This sysctl command will return the same key value pair.

```
sysctl -e -q vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = xxxxxx
```

This sysctl command will return the same key value pair.

```
sysctl -e -q vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = xxxxxx
```

This sysctl command will return the same key value pair.

```
sysctl -n -e -q vm.max_map_count
xxxxxx
```

There is your answer.  However, I would rather open /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count as a file and read the value verses executing a process from a C program.  Calling sysctl in a bash script to set a variable would make more sense.

```
vmval=`sysctl -n -e -q vm.max_map_count`
echo $vmval
xxxxxx
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. I meant - how to get those values programmatically, through an API.  Using bash scripts as a mandatory execution requirement is not an option in my case.